# How to package the couchdb indexes in external chaincode build?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am trying to install and deploy the chaincode as external service following the instructions [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/cc_service.html)

I have created the **couchdb indexes** following the instructions [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html#add-the-index-to-your-chaincode-folder) and package the chaincode as:

- package the **META-INF directory** along with the connection.json which outputs "code.tar.gz"
- package the **META-INF directory** along with "code.tar.gz" and "metadata.json" which outputs "cc_name.tgz"

*Both of these methods resulted in error while installing the chaincode using **peer lifecycle command**.*

I installed the chaincode without packaging the META-INF (couchd indexes) and everything works as expected. But for blockchain application I have few situations where I need to query data from couchdb and update the assets in the ledger.

What's the correct way to package the couchdb indexes when deploying the chaincode externally?

Answer (score 5):

Inside `code.tar.gz`:

`mychaincode@0.0.1.tar.gz` -> `code.tar.gz`-> `META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes/myindex.json`.

Anyway, I would advise to use [IBM Blockchain Platform VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform) to ease the packaging and other kind of operations.

To make use of your indexes, use `use_index` in your rich queries (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.1/api/database/find.html).

Comment: thanks! my issue was i hadn't copied over the META-INF in the build and release scripts as mentioned in the docs: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/cc_launcher.html